# ie10 uri redirect not working, Win8 RTM desktop

Tags: oauth, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

NOT the  (fka Metro) style IE10, but the desktop version.
I have an app that accesses Dropbox. OAuth works fine with IE9 and other browsers.
However, on Win8RTM, IE10 doesn't accept the URI redirect after I login to Dropbox and approve my app's access. 
Once I approve access, Dropbox returns a URI to open my app and pass it the new token. In IE10, it fails: error Cannot handle https....

I changed the default browser to the latest Chrome, and it worked fine.
I even added Dropbox to my Trusted Sites list.
Works fine in IE9 on my Win7 test box.
Here's a link to my beta. Just need to fix this setup issue and do the graphics for the buttons and its finished.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17111851/SMARTLIST.ZIP

Comment: By design, never implemented for IE --keeps getting postponed. Used workaround.